# ajaxtoolkit AutoCompleteExtender not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete, textbox

Trying to get an autocomplete to work an a textbox but it seems that the code behind method is never firing. Can anyone see the issue from below? I have tried various samples/tutorials to no effect.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="SM1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtUserName" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
            MinimumPrefixLength="2" CompletionInterval="10" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="3" UseContextKey="True">
            </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

code behind:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
   string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WMSDatabase"].ConnectionString;
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
   // Try to use parameterized inline query/sp to protect sql injection
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP " + count + " Alias FROM dbo.Users WHERE Alias LIKE '" + prefixText + "%'", conn);
   SqlDataReader oReader;
   conn.Open();
   List<string> CompletionSet = new List<string>();
   oReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
   while (oReader.Read())
   CompletionSet.Add(oReader["Alias"].ToString());
   return CompletionSet.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try removing the update panel from your code:**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="SM1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtUserName" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
            MinimumPrefixLength="2" CompletionInterval="10" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="3" UseContextKey="True">
            </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Comment: I have actually followed this sample here: http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=777 on a new blank website and it does work! The only thing which does not work on my current project is that when I click the textbox and select Add AutoComplete page method I get "Cannot create page method "GetCompletionList" because no CodeBehind or CodeFile was found!" which is not true of course.

Comment: You were right, thanks, It was due to the UpdatePanel. Works great now. One last question, if no entries are found I know I can return a string[] with "No entries found." but how to make it so that you can't actually click on the "No entries found" text so that it won't populate with the textbox with that?

Comment: Also, If you are using PageMethods set EnablePageMethods="true" in your Script Manager.